# Detecting autofill of login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, autofill

I am trying to create a webpage with a login page. When the user logs in for the first time the username and password will be saved by the browser, if he checks "Stay logged in". When he logs in the second time the browser will autofill the form and I can log him in without any need for him to interact with the page.

The problem is, that I can't get the password from the login form. Take a look at my code:

```
$(document).ready(setTimeout(function() {
  loginForm.form.submit(function(e) { // I don't have a onsubmit action defined on the login form
    console.log("Submit");
    checkLogin(); // This function should get the username and password value and makes a credential check but I cant get the password here
  });
  var username = $(".login-form__username").val();
  var password = $(".login-form__password").val(); // This always is "", an empty string!
  if (username) { // If the username is set we assume its an autofill
    console.log("autofilled");
    loginForm.form.submit(); // I manually fire the submit event when the browser autofills the username and password field
  }
}, 100));
```

I can clearly see, that the username and password are filled in to the form, but somehow I cant get the password. Everything goes well If I manually click on the submit button of the form. This will of course trigger `checkLogin();` and I can get the password here. But it wont work, if I trigger the event manually after the document ready event.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or why this happens?

Thanks, David

**EDIT**

I just figured out, that this **issue only appears on Chrome for Mac**, it works like a charm on Chrome for Windows and on Firefox. This don't works on Safari, because you need to select the user you want to login.

In addition I also figured out, that the focus needs to be set to the Webpage itselfe, not on the URL-Bar or on the refreshButton

Comment: You're setting `username` and `password` when the page is first loaded, not when the user submits the form.

Comment: What is `loginForm.username.val()`?

Comment: @Barmar This two lines are just to verify if the browser autofilled the form. So if usernames value is not empty it will trigger the submit event. I'll edit my question

Comment: @lshettyl I updated my question its the same as `$(".login-form__username").val()`

Comment: This might be helpful http://tbosch.github.io/autofill-event/src/autofill-event.js

Answer (score 1):

"Stay logged in" and the browsers Autofill are two pair of shoes. "Stay logged in" is normally implemented by a cookie or a local store which contains the current user information. A script running on your page checks that and logs the user in or sends him to the login form.

The autofill is a browser feature where the user is asked to store the credentials in the browser. You don't know via javascript if the is something stored.
But you could try to check the length of the content of you input and blindly submit it. If it works the credentials were right.

Comment: That seems to be what he's trying to do. He checks whether the username field is already filled in.

Comment: @localghost Yes, thats what I am doing. I am trying to login with the given credentials from the browser if he fills them in my form. If the credentials are wrong I'll notify the user. I cant use cookies, because this website runs on a small special designed Server. And its not easy for him to do the cookie stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Store Form USername And Password In Local Storage Of Browser

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "Danyial.com");
localStorage.setItem("password", "1234567901");
```

And Get The Value And Put In Form

```
  var username =localStorage.getItem("username"); 
  var password =localStorage.getItem("password"); 
  $(".login-form__username").val(username);
  $(".login-form__password").val(password);
```